# Did I fall into a strange A/B test? The "alert" dot looks a lot less "alert"-y on the Jobs page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Not sure what's going on here, so I'll show links and pictures.

This is what I see [when I visit this job posting](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/156471/java-developer-aib?med=clc):

[image]

This is what I see on the main page:

[image]

Seems like the alert dot is a lot less prominent on that page.  Could I have fallen in a strange A/B test case?

Comment: It is a size indicator for the number of items in the queue ....

Comment: @rene:  Then why is that indicator a different size on the Jobs tab but *nowhere else*?

Comment: the whole topbar is slightly different. The active tab indicator has whitespace as well. It simply isn't the same thing ...

Comment: They obviously don't want to distract the Jobs viewers with menial janitorial duties.

Comment: @rene:  Outside of the dot I can see no visual difference between these two top bars.  I'm confused by your remarks.

Comment: @Makoto The headers on the left are higher up for me in Jobs, and the highlighted line under the current tab is in a different height.

Comment: @Makoto see screenshot with RFHC https://i.stack.imgur.com/hETqi.png. I'm on Chrome/Win10 in case we enter the area of browser glitches.

Comment: Can't wait to see that red dot appear again...

Comment: Get some rep @TGrif .. the close vote queue is always full ...

Comment: @rene:  Okay, now I'm on the same page.  I'm seeing this in Chrome (beta channel) on Linux and can't really speak to the precise issues you're encountering, but I can see that this topbar is in need of attention.

Comment: Looks like this is a simple bug. The team will investigate it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: "Alerty" is definitely an adjective I am planning to use in my daily life from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting, we've had some overwriting CSS on Jobs. Fix for this is now waiting in repo for build and should be up in few hours.

Answer (score 22):

This is because there is an additional CSS file, **jobs.css**, on the Jobs page; this jobs.css file is applying `box-sizing: border:box` to `*::after` pseudo-elements, and `box-sizing: inherit;` to `#content` children of `*::after` pseudo-elements. Remove those styles and you will see it return to its normal size overlapping the corner of the review icon. Definitely an inadvertent bug.