# "Attention required" red dot not shown in the review screens

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

When I go to a review screen as the result of red dot in the top bar, the red dot disappears.

This encourages me to stop reviewing. Checking the contents under the review button shows that more reviewing is still needed, but the subconscious nudge to be done is very strong.

I think that every review screen should have its own big red dot that shows whether this screen needs more TLC at the moment.

If that is too hard, maybe just keep showing the red dot in the top bar until the current queue no longer needs attention?

Comment: They obviously don't want to distract reviewers with menial janitorial duties.  [:P](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357373/did-i-fall-into-a-strange-a-b-test-the-alert-dot-looks-a-lot-less-alert-y-o#comment519116_357373)

Comment: The Sanitation And Neatness Team should not be distracted with menial janitorial duties, very true.

Comment: I never realized what a blessing it was to get my bug reports from customers that are not programmers.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the goal of the red dot is to cause you to *look* at the review queues, and the fact that users engage with it afterwards [is an artifact of them clicking on it in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red).  Notice in that graph, the number of users actually engaging is lower than the number of users who clicked in the first place.

I'm not sure that the red dot would do anything more to convince a user to look at the queues than what has already been done.  The goal was to get you over to the review queues.  It did.  If you don't want to review after that, then that's up to you, but the fact that you actually went to find out what that dot was about is a good thing from my perspective.

*Keeping* the dot there only muddies the message.  You're already reviewing; why do you need to inspect the dot again?

Comment: I (and I think at least some others) go to the review queue to clear up the visual disturbance that is the red dot. If you keep showing it as long as the queue we're editing is still "distressed", this subset of people will keep reviewing. Put in a different way, the disappearing red dot tells me that I am done with my job of reviewing, so I stop. But the queue is still distressed, so I am not really done. That's a misque

Comment: hiding the button has the same effect (eliminating the visual disturbance) with a lot less effort.